# Choosing between YUI Charts or Google Visualization API

Tags: javascript, charts, accessibility

I'm a bit stuck with which charting library I will use in my project. Im stuck with this two (but also open for other suggestions)

**For YUI Charts :**
 Pro :
 - Very robust and configurable
 Cons : 
 - Uses flash 9 >, which might potentially be inaccessible for users without up to date flash version
 - Does not support export to image (for flash versions < 10 only)

**For Google Visualization API**
 pros:
 - small file size for the libraries,
 - can be exported to static image charts (via separate API call)
 Cons
 - limited configuration options

So there, please help me decide. YUI charts has the edge over configuration options but Google Visualization API has the edge in terms of accessibility as it uses SVG to render the grapsh instead of Flash. For users that are hand-cuffed by corporate IT prohibitions , they cant just upgrade their Flash version and the page will not work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would choose Google's API as it requires only a javascript interpreter or internet access (to Google).

The fewer dependencies, the better. Not to mention there is quite an array of tools for manipulating SVG images.

If you really cannot make do without certain features in YUI or cannot find simpler ways to express your charts, then choose YUI.

Comment: Yes this is where Im stuck at. If I go with YUI then the page might not work if the flash version requirement is not satisfied. Then if I go with Google VisAPI, I would then give up many configuration options which can make our graph more presentable (like rotated labels for long texts, etc).

Comment: Please note that you can manipulate images in any language (python is my choice) and you can easily manipulate SVG with anything that can read/write a text file. Hence you could add rotated labels, etc,. Just tell the Google API to just give you a chart and add things to it after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a peek at http://www.simile-widgets.org/ It might be overkill / bad fit for your needs, but it is positively sexy.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want flash for drawing charts in your application it is better to choose
**Google Visualization API**...

The Google Visualization JavaScript API lets you access structured data and visualize that data using JavaScript in your web pages. The Google Visualization API also enables creation of gadgets.